# powerquery, creating table from delimited list of delimited lists, containing delimited key value pairs

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to create a table from a text field, which is a delimited list of delimited lists, containing delimited key value pairs.... I have absolutly no idea what the best way would to do this

This field is like this example,

```
key1=aaa,key2=aab,key3=aac|key1=aaa,key3=aax|key...
```

It goes on much more, but that captures the structure of the field data..

Comment: Impossible to tell without at least two sample input rows and sample of desired output.  It might just be as simple as [ split on | ]  [split on , ] then  [ split on =  ]

Answer (score 0):

```
(Text as nullable text) as nullable table =>
    try
        Table.FromRecords(
            List.Transform(
                Text.Split(Text, "|"),
                (r) =>
                    let
                        SplitAnyList = Text.SplitAny(r, "=,"),
                        Record =
                            Record.FromList(
                                List.Alternate(SplitAnyList, 1, 1),
                                List.Alternate(SplitAnyList, 1, 1, 1)
                            )
                    in
                        Record
            )
        )
    otherwise null
```

Creates a table, with keys as columns.